# Building Progressive Web Apps using Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to build PWA's with Flask? More specifically, is it possible to register a service worker using Flask template rendering? If so, could anyone give some information on how to go about that or point to some resources? Because I was unable to find anything. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

App structure

```
app
    static
        css
            page.css
        js
            app.js
        sw.js

    templates
        index.html

    app.py
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/sw.js', methods=['GET'])
def sw():
    return app.send_static_file('sw.js')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/page.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register("../sw.js").then(function(registration) {
                    // Registration was successful
                    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
                }, function(err) {
                    // registration failed :(
                    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'navigator.serviceWorker.register("../sw.js")' should be 'navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js")'. If you use the first the navigator will look for a new service worker(and not find one) wherever it is rather than recognizing the first one registered.

Comment: I always get "ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:5000/') with script ('http://localhost:5000/sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain')."